# setting max-height not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not able to set maximum height on the slider I am using, every height I set doesn't seem to be working. I have also tried setting the width on echo img row on the php part but it is not working. How do I set max height? I want height not to be morethan `500px;`

The slider height in javascript file is set to 500px;

```
<div style="margin:30px auto;max-width:499px;max-height:500px">
<div id="amazingslider-1" style="display:block;position:relative;margin:16px auto ">
<ul class="amazingslider-slides" style="display:none;">

<?php
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$path = 'uploaded_files/';
echo "<li>"."<img src='".$path."".$row['image_one']."' style='width:500px;height:500px;'/></li>";
}   
$mydb->close ();
?>
    </ul>
    <ul class="amazingslider-thumbnails" style="display:none;">
        <li><img src="images/1-tn.jpg" /></li>

    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You referring to line 1 in your code right?

Comment: yep. `max-height:500px`

Comment: Well image height is 500px alone in PHP so everything else is going to push it... if its going overspill one option is `overflow` which allows a scroll bar on the div if the content inside is longer than the height of the div (meaning you only need `height:500px` rather than max height.

Answer (score 0):

If the content is forcing the height of the div to be larger than 500px and you want the div to remain at 500px, you can set the div's overflow to either `hidden` or `scroll`:

```
<div style="margin:30px auto;max-width:499px;max-height:500px;overflow:scroll">
    ...whatever content
</div>
```

Full example: http://jsfiddle.net/tY5bZ/1/

Comment: Or overflow:auto then scroll bar will only appear when content is larger than div.

Comment: this works but not what I want. Why the php style isn't working?